# Anyone have sample code for doing a "chunked" HTTP streaming download of one web directly to a upload to a separate web server?

Tags: c#, http, httpwebrequest, streaming, chunked-encoding

**Background** - I'm trying to stream an existing webpage to a separate web application, using HttpWebRequest/HttpWebResponse in C#. One issue I'm striking is that I'm trying to set the file upload request content-length using the file download's content-length, HOWEVER the issue seems to be when the source webpage is on a webserver for which the HttpWebResponse doesn't provide a content length.

```
HttpWebRequest downloadRequest = WebRequest.Create(new Uri("downloaduri")) as HttpWebRequest;
 using (HttpWebResponse downloadResponse = downloadRequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
 {
   var uploadRequest = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(new Uri("uripath"));
   uploadRequest.Method = "POST";
   uploadRequest.ContentLength = downloadResponse.ContentLength;  // ####
```

**QUESTION** : How could I update this approach to cater for this case (when the download response doesn't have a content-length set). Would it be to somehow use a MemoryStream perhaps? Any sample code would be appreciated.  **In particular is there a code sample someone would have that shows how to do a "chunked" HTTP download & upload to avoid any issues of the source web server not providing content-length?**

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I already applied in the Microsoft Forums, there are a couple of options that you have.

However, this is how I would do it with a `MemoryStream`:

```
HttpWebRequest downloadRequest = WebRequest.Create(new Uri("downloaduri")) as HttpWebRequest;

byte [] buffer = new byte[4096];
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
using (HttpWebResponse downloadResponse = downloadRequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
{
    Stream respStream = downloadResponse.GetResponseStream();
    int read = respStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

    while(read > 0)
    {
        ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
        read = respStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    }

    // get the data of the stream
    byte [] uploadData = ms.ToArray();

    var uploadRequest = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(new Uri("uripath"));
    uploadRequest.Method = "POST";
    uploadRequest.ContentLength = uploadData.Length;

    // you know what to do after this....
}
```

Also, note that you really don't need to worry about knowing the value for `ContentLength` a priori. As you have guessed, you could have set `SendChunked` to `true` on `uploadRequest`, and then just copied from the download stream into the upload stream. Or, you can just do the copy without setting `chunked`, and `HttpWebRequest` (as far as I know) will buffer the data internally (make sure `AllowWriteStreamBuffering` is set to `true` on `uploadrequest`) and figure out the content length and send the request.