# Large file sized can't download with file transfer plugin in windows phone

Tags: cordova, windows-phone, file-transfer

I am working with file download and open with using [File transfer plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer) and open with [childbrowser plugin](https://github.com/alunny/ChildBrowser) in windows and for android and ios i am using [file opener plugin](https://github.com/pwlin/cordova-plugin-file-opener2).

**Issue:** I can download and open less then 2 MB file without any issue for all platforms android,ios and windows phone. But for more then 2 MB file can't able download for windows phone getting error like "**system.outofmemoryexception**" where ios and android working fine with even big sized file.

Please advice me for download more then 2 MB sized file in windows phone using [File transfer plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer).

Comment: Similar to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31565374/phonegap-downloading-large-files-on-windows-phones

Comment: not working, i tried already...

Comment: Do you mean `wp8` or `windows` platform by `windows phone`? Have you tried enabling [Chunked mode](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer#upload)?

Comment: I am working on windows phone 8.1 and need to do with Cordova plugin.

Comment: @Naitik do you use `cordova platform add wp8` or `cordova platform add windows`?

Comment: i used cordova platform add wp8

Comment: OK consider moving to `windows` then as `wp8` is deprecated. Also you could check chunkedMode=true.

Comment: Where should i checked chunkmode?

Comment: Take a look at this code: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1869664/4177762 Or use `cordova platform add windows` instead of wp8 if possible.

Comment: No in my case not possible sorry